# How to change the color of the ActivityIndicator in React Native (Android)?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I need to change the color of the ActivityIndicator to black but only in this area of the app.  I do not want to change it anywhere else.  Does anyone know how to change its color for both Android and iOS?

```
<ActivityIndicator 
    style={{position: 'absolute', right: 20, margin: 0, padding: 0}}
    animating={true}
    size='small'
/>
```

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicator.html#color

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
 <ActivityIndicator color="#000000"/>
```

You can check more props in the [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicator.html#color)

Comment: Can we use multiple colors like we use in refreshControl?

Comment: "colors={['#ff0000', '#008000', '#0000ff']}"  Will this work?

Comment: any idea how to change the color of a FlatList refresh control?

Answer (score 4):

You can make a reusable component and override the color where ever you want.

**Spinner.js:**

```
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";

const Spinner = props => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.spinnerStyle}>
      <ActivityIndicator color={props.color || "#000000"} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  spinnerStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
};

export default Spinner;
```

By the way, you can set that `#000000` as the default color!

And where you want to use it, just import that in that file and use it as a component:

**YourFile.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import Spinner from "PATH_TO_SPINNER/Spinner";

class MyClass extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Spinner color="#663399" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you declaring a new component that just takes the color and puts it in the exact same field ? Why not just use the `color` attribute in `ActivityIndicator` (see @Tarik's answer) ?

Comment: That's just an example! In this way, you can customize your component!

Comment: Unfortunately this wasn't OP's question. Tarik's answer is far more straightforward

Answer (score 0):

> You need to add color as a prop to your ActivityIndicator like the code below.

```
<ActivityIndicator 
   style={{position: 'absolute', right: 20, margin: 0, padding: 0}}
   animating={true}
   size='small'
   color='#fff' 
/>
```

> You can see more about it [ActivityIndicator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicator.html#color)
>
> If you want to use other styles of ActivityIndicator, it is a good plugin to use [ActivityIndicator Collection](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-indicators/blob/master/readme.md)